# Linking multiple inputs "form" with Ruby method in a Rails project

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Im using this [Gem](https://github.com/jazminschroeder/fedex) for Fedex Web services and being really new to Ruby/Rails i need help figure out how to start using this gem within my application.

This is what i got so far...

`test.html.erb`

```
<h4>Shipper</h4>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postal Code">
    </div>

<h4>Recipient</h4>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postal Code">
    </div>

<%= button_to "Generate Rate" %

<h4>Total Cost</h4>
<%= "Output Here" %>
```

Now with the inputs to collect the shipper and receipt address, i need to know run query to the api through the following script.

`test_helper.rb`

```
require 'fedex'

def fedex
   test_creds = {...mycreds...}
   fedex_test = Fedex::Shipment.new(test_creds)
   recipient = {:name => "Recipient",
                       :company => "Company",
                       :phone_number => "555-555-5555",
                       :address => "1211 Burke Street",
                       :city => "Cambridge",
                       :state => "CA",
                       :postal_code => "02141",
                       :country_code => "MA",
                       :residential => "false" }
   shipper = { :name => "Bob Jones",
              :company => "Test Company",
              :phone_number => "777-777-7777",
              :address => "8799 W. Music Ln",
              :city => "Netherland",
              :state => "AD",
              :postal_code => "89045",
              :country_code => "US" }
   packages = []
   packages << {
    :weight => {:units => "LB", :value => 6},
    :dimensions => {:length => 26, :width => 9, :height => 2, :units => "IN" }
   }            
   shipping_options = {
        :packaging_type => "YOUR_PACKAGING",
        :drop_off_type => "REGULAR_PICKUP"
   }
   rates = fedex_test.rate({:shipper=>shipper, :recipient => recipient, :packages => packages, :service_type => "FEDEX_GROUND", :shipping_options => shipping_options})
   rates.to_s
```

### What i need

Im trying to figure out how to easily link the html inputs "forms" and their values that are enter with the hash's within the ruby code. Im looking to have this triggered by the button click.

Any help, links to help, suggestions, code examples are very helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, I'd implement an ActiveModel model which would encapsulate all the necessary attributes to calculate Fedex rates. This model then is usable in form helper.

Something along these lines. Note: you could come up with a better naming :)

```
# models/fedex_rates.rb
require 'fedex'

class FedexRates
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :shippper_address, :shippper_city, :shippper_state, :shippper_postal_code
  attr_accessor :recipient_address, :recipient_city, :recipient_state, :recipient_postal_code

  def perform
    recipient = {
      name:    recipient_name
      company: recipient_company
      address: recipient_address
      city:    recipient_city
      state:   recipient_state
    }

    shipper = {
      # Set attributes
    }

    #  ... Code to set up packages.

    fedex_test.rate({ shipper:shipper, recipient: recipient })
  end
end
```

Create an appropriate view using rails form_for helper method.

```
# views/fedex_rates/news.html.erb.
<%= form_for @fedex_rates do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :recipient_address %>
  <%= f.text_field :recipient_city %>
  <%= f.text_field :recipient_state %>
  <%= f.text_field :recipient_postal_code %>  

  <%= f.text_field :shipper_address %>
  <%= f.text_field :shipper_city %>
  <%= f.text_field :shipper_state %>
  <%= f.text_field :shipper_postal_code %>
<%= end %>
```

Implement controller.

```
# controllers/fedex_rates_controller.rb
class FedexRates < ApplicationController
  def new
    @fedex_rates = FedexRates.new
  end

  def create
    fedex_rates = FedexRates.new(params[:fedex_rates])
    rates = fedex_rates.perform

    # Do something with the rates
  end
end
```

Add routes

```
# routes
resources :fedex_rates, only: [:new, :create]
```